# Typescript debugger in vscode not stoping at breakpoints

Tags: typescript, debugging, visual-studio-code

i have an issue with debugger in vscode, debugger not stoping at defined breakpoints, my index.ts file:
[index.ts file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SVKol.png)

I can see them on breakpoints list in vscode:
[debugger breakpoints list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/od7Qk.png)

My tsconfig:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["es2020"],
    "target": "es2020",
    "outDir": "build",
    "module": "CommonJS",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "sourceMap": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "./node_modules"
  ]
}
```

launch.json file:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "pwa-node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Program",
            "skipFiles": ["<node_internals>/**"],
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/build/index.js",
            "outFiles": ["${workspaceFolder}/build/**/*.js"],
            "args": ["../questions"],
            "env": { "NODE_ENV": "development" },
            "resolveSourceMapLocations": [
              "${workspaceFolder}/**",
              "!**/node_modules/**"
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "prepare app to debug",
            "postDebugTask": "clean app after debug",
            "stopOnEntry": true,
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "sourceMaps": true
          }
    ]
}
```

tasks.json file:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "npm",
            "script": "build",
            "group": "build",
            "label": "npm: build - app",
            "detail": "NODE_ENV=development tsc -p ."
        },
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "clean app",
            "command": "rm -rf ./build"
        },
        {
            "label": "prepare app to debug",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "echo prepare app to debug",
            "dependsOrder": "sequence",
            "dependsOn": [
                "npm: build - app"
            ]
        },
        {
            "label": "clean app after debug",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "echo clean app after debug",
            "dependsOrder": "sequence",
            "dependsOn": [
                "clean app"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

And this is my run scripts in package.json file:

```
"build": "tsc",
"start": "ts-node src/index.ts",
"dev": "nodemon --watch 'src/**/*.ts' --ignore 'src/**/*.spec.ts' --exec 'ts-node' src/index.ts"
```

In debugging i'm using only `build` script.
When i'm clicking green arrow in debbug section on selected "Launch Program" it starts running scripts, and everything runs perfectly, but debugger is not stoping at breakpoints. Also i can see that breakpoints in code are moved from red to gray with "unmounted breakpoint" label.